# Можно ли сказать "нарвать грибы"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Попалось в тексте "нарвать грибы" и как-то резануло. Разве по отношению к грибам можно сказать "нарвать"? По-моему, грибы собираются. И, кстати, "нарвать (насобирать) грибы" или "нарвать (насобирать) грибов"?

Comment: Грибы не собираются (что, они в группки, что ли, кучкуются?) - их собирают.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По данным словаря сочетаемости, грибы можно найти, сорвать, срезать, собрать.  А значит и нарвать, т.е. срывая, набрать (см. Ожегова). Возможно, эти варианты различаются стилистически. Собрать грибы - собрать определенное количество, собрать грибов  - собрать неопределенное количество.

Comment: Ларf, Вам не кажется, что если СОрвать грибы сказать  можно, то НАрвать всё-таки не что?- грибы ,а чего?- грибов?

Comment: "...а значит и нарвать". Нет, не значит. Грибы *нарвать* нельзя. Ну, давайте хотя бы обозначать стремление к доказательности! Аргументация своим вкусом тоже имеет значение, но она ведь в этом ряду последняя. Сначала идут:

1. Авторитетные русские тексты.

2. Теория. 

3. Словари. Словарь сочетаемости. Сочетание "нарвать грибы(ов)" отсутствует.

4. И только здесь - "как мне кажется, ...".

Силлогизм "раз можно *срывая, набрать*, то можно и *нарвать*" - ну никак не *теория*, только пункт 4. Не могли бы вы привести примеры такого словоупотребления в (более-менее) классической русской речи?

Answer (score 1):

Но всё же в речи чаше слышишь "Собирали грибы", "Набрали грибов".

Comment: Вот и мне так кажется.

Answer (score 0):

Формально сочетаться эти слова могут, но в слове "нарвать" есть какой-то оттенок небрежности. Шёл по дороге и походя нарвал охапку цветов, нарвал бумажек для жеребьёвки, без разницы одинаковые или нет, нарвал травы для кроликов, не заботясь о том какая трава под руку попадёт.

Грибы же в лесу всё-таки собирают аккуратно, чтоб червивый или ядовитый домой не утащить, а вот шампиньоны, у себя на участке выращенные, вполне и нарвать можно.

Comment: Что значит, "формально могут сочетаться"? Глокая куздра? Речь ведь идёт здесь именно о смысловой, лексической сочетаемости. А её можно доказать только примерами словоупотребления. Можете привести цитату из более-менее литературного источника?

Comment: На грамоте.ру в качестве примера сочетаемости глагола "нарвать" приводится пример "Н. букет роз". Если по мнению составителей словаря можно нарвать букет, да ещё и колючих роз, то почему нельзя нарвать грибов непонятно. Другое дело, как я уже писал, что в слове "нарвать" есть оттенок небрежности действия, а грибы за редким исключением собирают аккуратно.
Как пример употребления выражения приведу слова Василия Игнатьевича из фильма Георгия Данелии "Осенний марафон" (1980),- "Я сегодня утром уже корзину грибов нарвал. А ты все спишь, лентяй."

Comment: "Осенний марафон" - подходит. *Небрежность* и *розы* в данном случае только ослабляют аргументацию.

Answer (score 0):

Дамы и Кавалеры!
Нормальные грибники грибы именно *рвут*. 
Некогда владеющая умами идея *срезать* грибы (якобы сохраняя грибницу) ничего общего с охраной природы не имеет: грибнице от того толку мало, а вот червям - раздолье.
Так что грибы вполне себе *вырывают*. Аккуратненько, с пониманием, но именно рвут. Если не роют.

Comment: *Рвать* можно лишь то, что оказывает сопротивление (траву, деревья с корнем...). Грибы можно, скорее, *вынимать*.